# H2O asfactor() for new data

Tags: data-manipulation, h2o, categorical-data, automl

I am using `hf[[x1, x2]] = hf[[x1, x2]].asfactor()` to transform `X1` and `X2` to categorical variables and then train a classification model with automl(). Now for the new and unseen data, how should I convert the data? If I simply use the above method, is there any guarantee that it will be transformed similar to transformation in training phase?

In scklearn you should save the fitted object and use it for transforming train and new dataset but here I have no idea what to do?!

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to convert them to categorical `.asfactor()`. It will treat the new transformed data the same as it will if it saw the levels earlier (it would be consistent).

If new levels are being transformed and predicted then it will be treated as unseen data and will follow [the majority direction](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/missing_values.html).